# Variable conditional not declaring as expected

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm prob missing something simple but I don't understand why this returns "undefined" in each console.log when I'm declaring the variable immediately before the console.log

```
            var timer;
            var timerCalc = Math.random()*2000;

            if (timerCalc > 1000){
                timer === 1000;
                console.log(timer);
            } else if  (timerCalc < 100) {
                timer === 100;
                console.log(timer);
            } else {
                timer === timerCalc;
                console.log(timer + " = between 100 and 1000");
            }
```

Comment: Because `===` doesn't assign value, but it checks equality.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing `===` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment). Use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

=== is for checking equivalency, use a single = to assign the variable.

So for example:

```
timer = 1000;
console.log(timer);  //will print out 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;
```

your variable is created but no value is associated it gonna be undefined

```
timer === 1000;
```

this condition is undefined === 1000 wich is false

```
console.log(timer);
```

no value is assinged to timer so it's gonna show undefined

Actually if you replace === (strict comparison) with = (assign) in your code the `console.log` will show 1000 in the first log and 100 in the second

Answer (score 0):

You are checking on equality not assigning value